# Back face detection

Tags: rendering, polygon

Suppose I have one convex polyhedron, I need to detect back face. And $N=(A, B, C)$ is normal vector of polygon surface and vector $V$ in viewing direction. According to books formula and internet content if $V. N>0$ then polygon is back face otherwise front face.

We know that $V. N=|V|.|N|cos\theta$ from this when we consider
$\pi/2<\theta<=\pi$ then $V. N<0$ $\implies$ front face. And when we consider  $0°<=\theta<=\pi/2$ then $V. N>0$ $\implies$ back face.

**Case:1**
Now suppose in this case for front face where $V$ and $N$ are parallel to each then they makes angle 0°.Then we get $V. N>0$ but according to books formula when $V. N<0$ then we will get front face.

:[image]

**Case:2** Again I consider the case for back face where $V$ along with $N$ then they makes angle 180°.Then
we get $V. N<0$ but according to books formula when $V. N>0$ then we will get back face. [image]

My question is where I mistaken to understand the detect the back face and front face for the above cases with formula
$V. N >0   or   <0?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now suppose in this case for front face where V and N are parallel to each then they makes angle 0°.

In your example, V and N are pointing in opposite directions. The angle between them is 180 degrees, so the cosine is -1. Similarly:

> Again I consider the case for back face where V along with N then they makes angle 180°.

If V and N are pointing in the same direction, then the angle between them is 0 degrees, so the cosine is 1.

You have these backwards; that's why you're getting the wrong value.

Comment: if I consider N for front face with the same direction of V that means if I consider N is opposite  side of front face, then V and N has 0° angle, then above formula flipped for front face and back face?

Comment: @Sagorika The formula is sensitive to the way you calculate *N* from the points of the face. If *N = (A,B,C)*, then also *-N = (C,B,A)*. So when checking each face, you must be careful to order the points correctly and consistently.

Comment: @luser droog if I consider N for front face with the same direction of V that means if I consider N is opposite side of front face, then V and N has 0° angle, then above formula flipped for front face and back face, that means front face formula and angles becomes back face formula and angle and vice versa? Am I correct?

Comment: @Sagorika: Your comment didn't make any more sense the second time you repeated it than the first. N cannot be both the front face and the opposite side of the front face at the same time. So your question is gibberish.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I am saying instead of N pointing towards me, it pointing opposite side of the front face then front face formula and angle flipped with back face formula and angle?

Comment: @Sagorika: In the "front face formula", N is what *defines* which face is the front face. You cannot point N in the opposite direction without also saying that the front face is in the opposite direction. At which point, it is a different polygon.

Comment: @Sagorika The formula I have in mind is *N(A,B,C)=(B-A)×(C-B)* where × is the cross product. If you exchange A and C, then the resulting vector will point in the opposite direction. I encountered this problem when trying to draw [the Utah teapot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14600918/733077). Some of my patches had  a different orientation (and I didn't want to change the data) so I couldn't use the normal vector to determine visibility at all. But if you have control of the code(and/or data) then you can arrange things so all the faces point outward.

Comment: @Sagorika I'm not certain that this is the problem you are having. But I do know that this is one problem that could lead to the situation you describe so it's a good wrinkle for the cold iron.